# PHP socket receive many data at same time

Tags: javascript, php, sockets

I'm using PHP and WebSocket (JavaScript) to communicate between client and server. The process is:
    - Server start the socket, the client connects to.
    - When server have new data, it notifies all clients. 
    - Then client feedback received notification, server receives this information and will not sent that information again. If the client does not respond after 10 seconds, the server will be sent again.

Case server sent to client server many message once time, client answer server constantly server can not read the data.
Or when many clients reply at the same time, server neither can not read the data.

Sever using the function 'socket_recv' to receive data from the client.
Problem is how to get message in server.

Detail code:

```
// Create socket and start listen
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, 1155);
socket_listen($socket);

while (true) {
    // Check for new data and sent to all clients
    ..........
    ..........
    // End of test data and sent

    // Check if there are new data from the client
    $changed = $clients;
    socket_select($changed, $ null, $ null, 0, 10);

    // Run through the client
    foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) {
        // Read the information sent to the client
        while (socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0)> = 1)
        {
            // Use of client information check up and remove the message was the reply of the client
        }
    }

    sleep (1); 

}
```

Comment: check php manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php

Comment: I tried many options in the socket_recv, but it didn't work.